# Firebase Authentication - Link a Twitter Account

Tags: javascript, authentication, twitter, oauth, firebase

I want to support linking a twitter account to a website users authentication through firebase. This means that according to the following link I need to get the credentials of the auth provider.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking#link-auth-provider-credentials-to-a-user-account

The docs show google, facebook and email. However I want to use twitter ... So looking at the API here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider#TwitterAuthProvider

I need to call:

```
var credential = firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider.credential(token,secret);
```

Which is a problem ... Do I really need to put the twitter auth secret in the plain text javascript? Obviously, this seems to be a security risk???

Answer (score -3):

There are two way for [Authenticate Using Twitter on Web App](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/twitter-login)

**1.** [Handle the sign-in flow with the Firebase SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/twitter-login#handle_the_sign-in_flow_with_the_firebase_sdk)

**2.** [Handle the sign-in flow manually](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/twitter-login#handle_the_sign-in_flow_manually)

You need to try **1** to get the credentials of the auth provider.

The easiest way to authenticate your users with Firebase using their **Twitter** accounts is to handle the sign-in flow with the Firebase SDK. To do so, follow these steps:

**Step 1:**
Create an instance of the Twitter provider object:

```
var provider = new firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider();
```

**Step 2:**
Authenticate with Firebase using the Twitter provider object. You can prompt your users to sign in with their Twitter accounts either by opening a pop-up window or by redirecting to the sign-in page. The redirect method is preferred on mobile devices.

- To sign in with a pop-up window, call **signInWithPopup**:

  ```
   firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
  // This gives you a the Twitter OAuth 1.0 Access Token and Secret.
  // You can use these server side with your app's credentials to access the Twitter API.
  var token = result.credential.accessToken;
  var secret = result.credential.secret;
  // The signed-in user info.
  var user = result.user;
  // ...
  }).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  // The email of the user's account used.
  var email = error.email;
  // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
  var credential = error.credential;
  // ...
  });
  ```

Also notice that you can retrieve the Twitter provider's OAuth token which can be **used** to **fetch additional data using the Twitter APIs.**

- To sign in by redirecting to the sign-in page, call **signInWithRedirect**:

  `firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);`

Then, you can also retrieve the Twitter provider's OAuth token by calling **getRedirectResult** when your page loads:

```
    firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then(function(result) {
  if (result.credential) {
    // This gives you a the Twitter OAuth 1.0 Access Token and Secret.
    // You can use these server side with your app's credentials to access the Twitter API.
    var token = result.credential.accessToken;
    var secret = result.credential.secret;
    // ...
  }
  // The signed-in user info.
  var user = result.user;
}).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  // The email of the user's account used.
  var email = error.email;
  // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
  var credential = error.credential;
  // ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that doesn't help as to link an account (as per: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking#link-auth-provider-credentials-to-a-user-account ) you don't call signInWithRedirect or signInWithPopup, you don't sign in with twitter.